# could I potentially dodge segmentation faults by adding ram?

Tags: c++

just as my title asks, im wondering if I can potetionally dodge segmention fault crashes of my program if I add more ram? any advice on how to dodge is appreciated but this question is quite crucial since it depends if ill upgrade to 32gb ram instead of 8

program is written in c++

Comment: The only way to be sure is to fix the bugs in your code.

Comment: Just throwing RAM at the problem is not the solution.  The solution is to find out why you get the segfaults.  Generally that means you did something bad in your code and no amount of ram is going to fix that.

Comment: Segmentation faults nothing have to do with ram, they're bugs of software.

Comment: I know that mate but I was just wondering if adding ram would potentially decrease the chance of it occuring, I want to know that specifically

Comment: jack, afaik segmentation faults is also due to memory leaks

Comment: @user7157477 Segmentation fault, is, typically, one of many possible manifestations of undefined behavior. And.. Undefined behavior is undefined - no amount of RAM will change that.

Comment: No, you need to buy a better programmer.

Comment: Memory leaks are a result of allocating memory but never deallocating it.

Answer (score 3):

Just like ["out of memory"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory/), "segmentation fault" does not refer to RAM.

In a typical modern computer, each process gets its own address space. That's just a bunch of addresses. Some of those addresses are likely to map to RAM but they can also map to ROM, to VRAM, to files on disk, or to anything else the operating system supports mapping to a process address space.

Segmentation faults are invalid accesses to parts of a process address space. They can be invalid because the address does not exist (because it wasn't mapped to anything), or because the address cannot be written to (because it was mapped in a read-only manner). They are caused by bugs in the program.

Adding RAM won't change the size or layout of any process address space.

Comment: I don't know if its a out of memory Segmentation fault, it goes something like Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. [Switching to Thread 3812.0x720] 0xfeeefeee in ?? () problem is that these occur like once a week or something and thats why i ask if its possible to minimize the chance by adding ram, but now after reading all your posts I got it, its not possible to minimize the chance the slightest with ram, so it will only be wasting money to buy it

Answer (score 1):

No, memory an application sees is virtual. That means that the OS remaps the addresses the application sees to backing physical memory.

As an optimization memory the applciation doesn't request does not get mapped to real memory and if the application tries to access it will generate a fault.

So it doesn't matter wether you have 16 MB or 16 GB of physical ram. Segfaults happen when a bug in the program leads it to try and access memory that it never got.

Comment: okay thanks, when I read about memory I thought they meant ram, I know I have to fix them but minimizing the chance of them occuring is interesting to know but since they dont, I am going to save money not buying more ram :) so thanks for that